# Get score of 'O' (non-entity) in spacy

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I was comparing different Spacy V3 models for custom NER, I know exactly how to get scores per entity type with `!spacy evaluate output/model-best/ test.spacy`, but when looking at the result i am not getting a score for 'O'.

```
=============================== NER (per type) ===============================

                            P        R        F
...
FirstName               86.36    80.28    83.21
PlaceOfBirth            92.98   100.00    96.36
DateOfBirth             91.53    98.18    94.74
...
```

When i see all available classes, this 'O' is definitely in there `[ ... 'FirstName', 'Gender', 'LastName', 'O', 'PlaceOfBirth', ... ]`

Is there any possibility to get the score for 'O' to know how many tokens were recognized as an entity type or needed entity type that were recognized as 'O'

Kind regards